# Find and Update multiple objects in Mongoose js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**Problem:**
I wish to update multiple objects from my array schema.
What I have tried is, this suggestion below, which I found here: [Find and Update Object in Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45899615/find-and-update-object-in-mongoose)

Yes, this works, however, this will only update the first element on my messages_details array that holds the desired object.

```
await MessagesDetails
    .update(
        {
            _id : message_id,
            messages_details : {
                $elemMatch : {
                    user_id: user_id
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $set: {
                'messages_details.$.message_isRead': true,
            }
        }
    )
```

Here is my schema below:

```
const mongoose  = require('mongoose')
const Schema    = mongoose.Schema

const MessagesDetails = new Schema({
    _id : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    messages_details_subject : {
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    messages_details_sender : {
        type : Array,
        required : true
    },
    messages_details_recipient : {
        type : Array,
        required : true
    },
    messages_details_created : {
        type : Date,
        required : true
    },
    messages_details_updated : {
        type : Date,
        required : true
    },
    messages_details_isArchived : {
        type : Boolean,
        required : true
    },
    messages_details : [
        {
            user_id : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            user_username : {
                type : String,
                required : true
            },
            message_content : {
                type : String
            },
            message_date : {
                type : Date
            },
            message_isArchived : {
                type : Boolean
            },
            message_isRead : {
                type : Boolean
            }
        }
    ]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model( 'messages_details', MessagesDetails )
```

So my end goal here is, set the message_isRead to true based on these queries below;

```
_id 
messages_details.user_id
```

Could someone please enlighten me?

Comment: This might help you https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the right direction. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `$[]`-[operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#up._S_%5B%5D) for this:

```
await MessagesDetails
    .update(
        {
            _id : message_id,
            messages_details : {
                $elemMatch : {
                    user_id: user_id
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $set: {
                'messages_details.$[].message_isRead': true,
            }
        }
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Much appreciated.